# Callback in Node/Express ForEach

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, q

I have such Coffee-Code in my Express Router:

```
myObj = {}
files = [file1,file2]
files.forEach (file) ->
  # do stuff to fill up myObj with more data
  return myObj

res.status(202).send
  status: 'OK'
  payload: myObj 
return
```

Now how do I pass myObj from the forEach loop down to the http response part of my code?

This is what I am seeing:

```
ReferenceError: myObj is not defined
  at server/api/parse/parse.controller.js:494:14
  at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Comment: Hmmm, I am just wondering why passing `myObj` will not work as it is.

Comment: Should it work? I was wondering too, since it is declared outside function scope.

Comment: I am getting "is not defined", so somehow it is not passed on.

Comment: @SirBenBenji - Can you replicate the code here as is? This seems like an edited version and something is missing. As it, things should work.

Comment: In particular, we need to see `#do stuff to fill up myObj with more data`.

Comment: Agree, Will build a demo with original code on cloud 9, give me a day.